# Fetching a non-datetime string value from a column

Tags: mysql, regex, string, datetime

I recently ran a script to copy data from one large table (around 20 GB) to another, where I messed up, and the column values for a datetime column (called `timestamp`) got saved into another column with a varchar datatype (called `category_name`), while `timestamp` values have either been set to `NULL` or have a range of random datetime values (like `0000-00-00 00:00:00`, `0003-02-01 00:00:00`, `1990-12-00 00:00:00`, etc). The table I copied to also keeps getting new data. The new data however is not corrupted. I'm trying to determine the exact id of the rows from where my good data begins. Please note that valid values `category_name` column are either alphabetic values or `NULL`. I have tried the following queries -

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE `timestamp` IS NOT NULL 
AND `timestamp` != "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
ORDER BY id;
```

Which is when I discovered all kinds of values have been saved in the `timestamp` column.

I next tried

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE category_name REGEXP '[^a-zA-Z]' LIMIT 10;
```

which does not work.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE category_name REGEXP '[:alpha:]' LIMIT 10;
```

which does not work either.

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks. I'm just trying to get an approximate range of ids/rows from where my `category_name` column started getting valid data, and not datetime strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function. It returns NULL if can't convert String To Date. And also check if converted date is in range you need (in this example the last year `(CURDATE()-365)`)

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE `timestamp` IS NOT NULL 
AND LENGTH(`timestamp`)=19
AND IFNULL(STR_TO_DATE(`timestamp`,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s'),0)>CURDATE()-365 
ORDER BY id limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can change the format from a timestamp to a date http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp

http://forums.devshed.com/mysql-help-4/how-to-format-and-display-only-the-date-from-timestamp-1846.html

and then manipulate your data after that.

You might want to explore how to do this in PHP as well.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, but I cannot change the datatype or alter the table in any way as this table is live and receiving live data.

Comment: If you need an automated setup, try using an ETL studio, e.g. Talend, pentaho or jaspersoft etl on a dedicated server which you can schedule to run hourly, daily or however frequently you may need it to.

Comment: You can schedule an etl job to run when the server is not updating instead of having to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this problem using a backup of the database. I restored a backup of the database taken around the time I ran my script. Using that I was able to get the ids upto which my data got corrupted. I then moved my clean data (from that id onward) to this restored table and switched the table names. It took a while and resulted in loss of some data though.